# Addition of numbers entered in text boxes which are generated from a loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, textbox

I have a function which generate text boxes from a for loop

```
var txtBox = "<input type='text' id='txtNum[]' />"
for(var i = 0; i<=names.length;i++)//retrieve names from the array
    {
        html += "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+names[i]+"</td>";
        for(var j=1;j<=2;j++)//amount of textboxes need to be created
        {
            html+= "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+txtBox+"</td>";
        }
        for(var k=1;k<=1;k++)//amount of textboxes need to be created
        {
            html+= "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+txtBox+"</td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>";        
    }
```

this for loop will generate 3 text boxes in a row having the same id as long as the length of the names will not be met but my issue is that i want to compute let say addition of those value which will be entered in the text boxes but isn't having any luck figuring out a way to do this. I've searched online for examples but almost all of them are showing textboes with different id being compute, none that i saw with the id in form of an array.

I am limited to only javascript and html.

Any idea on how this can be achieved ??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can not re-use id's

Comment: any suggestion on what i can use to achieve what i want??

Comment: use a class name instead. Trying to re-use id's is by far the most common JS question here, so a little research before asking would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

First. IDs are IDs. There cannot be any other person with same ID as you have so there should not be two elements with same IDs. Use class instead. [HTML Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

For your problem. When you change it to class you can use

```
let arr = document.querySelectorAll(".CLASS_NAME")
```

[.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

or

```
let arr = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS_NAME')
```

[.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

to get an array of all input fields and then just

```
arr.ForEach((e)=>{
/*FUNCTION BODY HERE. HERE WILL BE ADDITION*/
let valueOfOneOfThem = parseInt(e.value) || 0;
sumOfAll += valueOfOneOfThem;
});
```

[.ForEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1uhnzjp/1/)

Comment: can you give me the full codes for what you suggested because i've tried but the result is coming undefined and nan..

Comment: Hey. I added jsFiddle for you. A working version. Look at it. I commented everything for you. :)